# Print the list of odd or even numbers between a range using python. Output should be in a single line along with the string

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
start=int(input('enter the starting range:'))
end=int(input('enter the ending range:'))
for d in range(start,end):
    if d%2!=0:
        print('The odd numbers between',start,'&',end,'is:',d)
```

Current output is:

```
enter the starting range:20
enter the ending range:30
The odd numbers between 20 & 30 is: 21
The odd numbers between 20 & 30 is: 23
The odd numbers between 20 & 30 is: 25
The odd numbers between 20 & 30 is: 27
The odd numbers between 20 & 30 is: 29
```

Wanted output is:

`'The odd numbers between 20 & 30 is: 21,23,25,27,29'`

What change do I need to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple and very neat solution: *(added my comments so you can understand what I did)*

```
start = int(input('enter the starting range: '))
end = int(input('enter the ending range: '))

#create an empty list
numbers = []
for d in range(start,end):
    if d % 2 != 0:
      #if number is odd, add it to the list
      numbers.append(d)

#we use end=" " to make sure there is no new line after first print
print('The odd numbers between',start,'&',end,'are:',end=" ")

#* symbol is used to print the list elements in a single line with space. To print all elements in new lines or separated by space use sep=”\n” or sep=”, ” respectively
print(*numbers,sep = ",")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension you could make it more shorter

```py
start=int(input('enter the starting range:'))
end=int(input('enter the ending range:'))

# New lines
numbers = ", ".join([str(i) for i in range(start, end) if i % 2 != 0])
print(f"The odds numbers between {start} and {end} are:", numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Print the message before the loop then the numbers during the loop:

```py
start = int(input('enter the starting range:'))
end = int(input('enter the ending range:'))
# use end='' to avoid printing a newline at the end
print(f'The odd numbers between {start} & {end} is: ', end='')
should_print_comma = False
for d in range(start,end):
    if d%2!=0:
        # only start printing commas after the first element
        if should_print_comma:
            print(',', end='')
        print(d, end='')
        should_print_comma = True
```

Comment: it will be helpful, if u can explain the should_print_comma concept....

Answer (score 0):

```py
start=int(input('enter the starting range:'))
end=int(input('enter the ending range:'))
s = ""
for d in range(start,end):
    if d%2!=0:
        s += str(d) + ", ";
print('The odd numbers between',start,'&',end,'is:',s)
```

You should probably put it in a function but that's just a preference.

Comment: This will result in `The odd numbers between 10 & 20 is: 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, ` with an extra comma at the end

Comment: add ```s = s[:-2]``` right before print (Do not indent). This removes the extra space and comma at the end of the string